# adding mysql rows in views.py

Tags: mysql, django

I am creating a powerlifting database, or trying too. I have a users Squat, deadlift and Bench Press amounts. Lets say i want to add just there deadlift and benchpress amounts, for example, but not store it, in mysql shell i do this:

```
mysql> SELECT sq, dl, bp, sq+dl AS sq_+_dlweight FROM mysite_weightsprofile
```

Ok, i get that.

In views i can do this as so:

```
conn = mdb.connect('localhost', 'bobby', '#########', 'website');
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT sq, dl, bp, sq+dl AS sq_+_dlweight FROM mysite_weightsprofile")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

However, this method seems quite convaluted, difficult to appropriate into templates and not very adjustable. Is there a way i can do the above using the short code

```
query_results = UserProfile.objects.all("?")
```

without having to create a cursor object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a method to your model. For instance:

```
class UserProfile(Model):
    squats = IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    deadlift = IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def squats_and_deadlifts(self):
        return self.squats + self.deadlift
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for user_profile in query_results %}
Deadlifts + squats: {{ user_profile.squats_and_deadlifts }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yes this would work, but lets say i wanted too add just squats and benchpress, or benchpress and deadlift, add to the mix 2 or 3 other exercises and wanting to mix and match weights might mean 20-30 variable combinatiopns. Creating a method for every combination means a lot of code. Is this as simple as it gets, or am i just being lazy

Comment: Well we want to separate logic from presentation so django won't allow you to do math in template. You may want to consider writing a multiplication template tag or filter per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/howto/custom-template-tags/